# Problems finding out total sum using data structures and arrays

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have this code that has several funtions and am almost done, I just am having trouble finding the rental cost on my program.
My program reads a text file of cars and the rental cost as shown here:

```
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1
2012 Mazda CX5 86.75 1
2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0
2015 Ford F150 200.83 1
2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1
```

The float character is the price ( rental cost )

However I want the user to input the car number ( 1-10) choose how many days and output the rental cost. I am just having trouble how it would read the input of the car the user wants. This is my main code, but what I need is to tell if case 3 needs work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct car {
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];
    float price;
    int available;

} ;

void menu();

// Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
int carAmount = 10;
int choice;
car carLib[carAmount];
char filename[10];
ifstream carInData;
float mostExpensive = 0;
int MostExpensiveIndex;
int count = 0;
int days;
int rentalCost = 0;
bool menu1 = false;

    //prompt user for input file
    cout << " Enter file name: ";
    cin >> filename;

    // Start loop menu
    while(menu1 = true){

    menu();

    carInData.open(filename);

    cin >> choice;

    if (carInData.is_open()) {
    // read list of names into array


       for (; count < carAmount; count++) {

        carInData >> carLib[count].year >> carLib[count].make >> carLib[count].model >> carLib[count].price >> carLib[count].available;

        }
    }

    switch (choice) {

   // Case 1 closes menu
    case 1:

    return 0;
    break;

    // Case 2 displays if car is available if 1, unavailable if 0
    case 2:

    // itterate through car array
    for(count = 0; count < carAmount; count++){

    // Displays if car is available or not 
    if (carLib[count].available == 1)
        cout << " Available ";
    else
        cout << " Unavailable ";

    // Display Cars
    cout << carLib[count].year << " " << carLib[count].make << " " << carLib[count].model << " " << carLib[count].price << "  " << "\n";
    }
    break;

    // Display only available cars
    case 3:

    // itterate through car array
    for(count = 0; count < carAmount; count++){

    // Displays only available cars
    if (carLib[count].available == 1){
        cout << " Available ";

    // Display Cars
    cout << carLib[count].year << " " << carLib[count].make << " " << carLib[count].model << " " << carLib[count].price << "  " << "\n";
      }
    }
    break;


    // Calculates  rental cost
    case 4:
    cout << " Enter car number and how many days " << "\n";
    cout << " Days: ";
    cin >> days;
    cout << "\n" << "Car: ";
    cin >> carLib[count].price;
    rentalCost += days*count;

    cout << " Rental Cost for " << days << " days is " << rentalCost << "\n";
    break;

    // Finds most expensive car
    case 5:

    MostExpensiveIndex = count;
    for (size_t carIndex = 0; carIndex < carAmount; ++carIndex) {

        if (carLib[carIndex].price <= mostExpensive) continue;
        mostExpensive = carLib[carIndex].price;
        MostExpensiveIndex = carIndex;

    }

    const car & carI = carLib[MostExpensiveIndex];

    cout << " Most Expensive car is: " << " " << carI.year << " " << carI.make << " " <<  carI.model << " "  << carI.price << "\n";

    break;



      }

    }

    return 0;
}


void menu()
{
    cout << " 1 - Exit program.\n";
    cout << " 2 - Show Cars\n"; 
    cout << " 3 - Show only available cars.\n";
    cout << " 4 - Rental Cost\n";
    cout << " 5 - Most Expensive Car\n";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you fixed the random, haphazard indentation of your code, once its laid out with proper, readable, logical indentation an easy solution will become apparent.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something with how your code is suppose to work, I think case 3 works fine. HOWEVER, it's case 4 that you should be worried about

```
      case 4:
            cout << " Enter car number and how many days " << "\n";
            cout << " Days: ";
            cin >> days;
            cout << "\n" << "Car: ";
            cin >> carLib[count].price;  // WHY IS THE USER CHANGING THE PRICE?
            rentalCost += days*count;    // WHY IS THE PRICE "DAYS * (CAR ID #)"

            cout << " Rental Cost for " << days << " days is " << rentalCost << "\n";
            break;
```

You can see my comments there. I would change this to

```
      case 4:
            cout << " Enter car number and how many days " << "\n";
            cout << " Days: ";
            cin >> days;
            cout << "\n" << "Car: ";
            cin >> count ;
            // Note the decrement of 'count' by one, since you expect the user
            // to enter a number 1-10
            // Should probably include a check that the 'count' is valid
            rentalCost += days*carLib[count-1].price;

            cout << " Rental Cost for " << days << " days is " << rentalCost << "\n";
            break;
```

Note that `carLib` increments from 0->9, but your user might think it counts from 1-10. It might help when you print option 2 (all car information) that you include the car ID number that you're expecting from the user.

Also a few more questions for you

- You're storing the rental cost as an `int` (not sure if that's by design), so just remember that the `days*price` computation will get rounded.
- The rentalCost is incrementing to be bigger and bigger, so I'm guessing the user is renting multiple cars?
- You should maybe do a check as to whether the user can actually rent a car before increasing their rental cost.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I just changed my rental cost to float to get the exact amount. I just registered each car to a certain number so the user knows. And the user is suppose to just check to rent each car individually. I did notice if the user tried to check other cars the price would add on from the previous one which isnt what i want.